# How can I import a TAB delimited file with double quote text qualifier into Excel if a cell value already contains a double quote?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to import a TAB delimited file with the following format into Excel 2013

```
"Column A"          "Column B"
"tjc0056421151r"    "I\gs]hü"nsf^f\F*lqog\düûWp"
"tjc0058088269r"    "EZacð0jrzmnbofofBÖÞRlXZi")["
```

When importing into Excel, the following format appears

```
Column A        Column B
tjc0056421151r  I\gs]hünsf^f\F*lqog\düûWp"
tjc0058088269r  EZacð0jrzmnbofofBÖÞRlXZi)["
```

**Example #1**

In B1 you will notice that the " has disappeared here:

```
hü"ns
```

and is now

```
hüns
```

**Example #2**

And in B2 you will notice that the " has disappeared here:

```
XZi")["
```

and is now

```
XZi)["
```

Excel has assumed that because there is a " in the value, that this is the closing " of the value, and has therefore stripped it.  The actual " at the end of the value, which should have been stripped, has remained.

Is there any option in Excel which prevents this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to disappear start and ending `"` and others to remain?

### Option 1

Use text editor with RegExp to text file (for example: [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)). Find and replace (sect option to allow RegExp)
Find: `^\"(.+)"\t"(.+)\"$`
Replace: `$1\t$2`
Now you can import without text qualifier.

### Option 2

Import without text qualifier selected and use [MS Office RegExp](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f#__available_wildcards) (in non-English version can be different syntax!).

### Option 3

Import without text qualifier and use Excel functions to remove first and last `"`.

```
=MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-2)
```